# Запуск 64битной виртуальной машины внутри виртуальной машины

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

При попытке запуска 64битной виртуальной машины (virtualbox/vagrant, далее гость/гость) внутри другой 64битной машины (чистый virtualbox, далее гость/хост) виртуалбокс выдает сообщение об ошибке (VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration is not available on your system). Соответствующая галка о включении VT-x/AMD-V в настройках машины гость/хост стоит, в выводе /proc/cpuinfo нет флагов vmx или svm. В чем может быть проблема и откуда начинать копать?

Лог виртуальной машины: [VBox.log](http://hastebin.com/vogivigoro.xml)

Comment: Если у вас нет железной поддержки этой технологии, ТОО наоборот вырубайте галку. /proc/cpu приложите и хоста.

Comment: Есть, конечно (я, конечно, слазаю в биос на следующем ребуте, но уверен, что там все включено, год назад проверял, когда наткнулся на конфликт vb/hyperv). У хоста нет /proc, это восьмая винда, команды для вывода флагов не нашел; у гость/хост в /proc/cpuinfo нужных флагов нету, как я уже написал, вот [полная версия](http://hastebin.com/igepowedak.hs) на всякий.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это абсолютно нормальное поведение. Вложенный запуск виртуальной машины внутри другой (*nested virtualization*), в том случае если в обоих случаях требуется аппаратная виртуализация (инструкции VMX, если мы говорим об Intel; и SVM, если мы говорим об AMD), до недавних пор — и об этом я скажу ниже — была невозможна.

В виртуальной машине аппаратные расширения виртуализации недоступны,
в чём вы легко можете убедиться, проверив флаги процессора внутри виртуальной машины:

```
$ grep vmx /proc/cpuinfo   # для Intel
$ grep svm /proc/cpuinfo   # для AMD
```

Что безусловно возможно и будет работать, это использование для вложенной виртуализации такой системы виртуализации, которая не требует аппаратных расширений. Например, *kqemu* или *xen* в паравиртуальном режиме.

[image: Три возможных варианта вложенной виртуализации]

В новых процессорах появились расширения, позволяющие выполнять вложенную аппаратную виртуализацию. Одна из таких это *VMCS Shadowing* и *EPT A/D bits* (Extended Page Table Accessed and Dirty bits).

Поддержка на уровне процессора появилась в последнем Xeon'е (Intel® Xeon® E5-2600 v3) в конце 2014 года. Поддержка со стороны программного обеспечения появилась впервые в Xen 4.4.

Подробнее:

- [Are you ready to innovate - four new Virtualization technologies on the latest Intel® Xeon!](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/09/08/four-new-virtualization-technologies-on-the-latest-intel-xeon-are-you-ready-to) (англ.)
- [Nested Virtualization in Xen](http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Nested_Virtualization_in_Xen) (англ.)

Что касается VirtualBox, то он названные технологии *не поддерживает*,
т.е. даже наличие соответствующего процессора у вас не исправило бы ситуацию.
Подробнее:

- [Ticket #4032 — Feature request — Nested Virtualization: VT-in-VT](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032) (англ.) — не обращайте внимание, что тикету уже больше 5 лет, обсуждение там продолжается, и в конце вы можете найти подробности о поддержке VMCS/EPT в VirtualBox, а точнее об её отсутствии

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Это печально, но в моей ситуации абсолютно некритично.